# Custom policies for AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to understand is it possible to use custom policies for AKS cluster.
According to documentation Azure Policy Add-on for Kubernetes cluster supports only built-in policy definitions. [Link to limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/policy-for-kubernetes#limitations).
I went through examples of built-in policies and didn't find anything specific that prevent me from creating own policy.
[Built-in policies](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/tree/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Kubernetes).
[OPA library](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/tree/master/library/general/requiredprobes) with example of the policy.

My goal is to create own policy that will check that all manifests have resource limits/requests to be defined.
Have someone faced with it and how have you resolved it?

Comment: What's stopping you from running OPA in your cluster?

Comment: Gatekeeper  is already running in the cluster.